# how to set axis limits in matlab globally?

Tags: matlab, plot

It seems trivial but I couldn't find a way to do it. I have `plot` in a function and I'm passing data from the main function. In the main function, I set the axes like this `axis([-10, 10, -10, 10]);`; however, every time I call the function which has `plot`, it changes the axes automatically. Is there a way to set the figure globally so that all functions can use one figure with fixed properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup x and y axis limits globally as follows (at least in R2013a):

```
set(0,'defaultaxesxlim',[-10 10]);
set(0,'defaultaxesylim',[-10 10]);
```