# How to set axis limits globally in MATLAB to min and max of data plotted?

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

I am trying to plot some figures in MATLAb. Once using the subplot feature to have several graphs beside each other the axis limits change, so I do not have them to the min and max of x and y and instead there is always some extra white space.

I'm trying to find a way to golobally set the x and y axis values to their min and max. I have approx 50 plots in my figure and for each plot x and y are named differently... Asking MATLAB everytime to limit tehe x and y to their min and max takes really time and adds to number of lines...

So is there any global way of defining this?

I have also looked at the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925329/how-to-set-axis-limits-in-matlab-globally), but it does not seem to answer my question.

This is a small dummy code, showing similar problem which I have with my graphs...

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,20); 
y = sin(x); 
figure(1) 
subplot(4,3,1)
plot(x,y)
title('Original')
fft_y = fft(y); 
subplot(4,3,2)
plot(abs(fft_y))
title('Spectrum')
subplot(4,3,3)
plot(angle(fft_y)) 
title('Phase')
```

[image]

Comment: "globally" is ill defined. Setting a default requires numbers, and you have `[0 8]` and `[0 400]`, which are different numbers. You'll have to set them per subfigure using `xlim([])`

Comment: All I wanna do is tellimg matlab for ecery plot u make set the x axis to its min and max and y to its min and max without me setting it... I was hoping there exists such a thing.

Comment: Best way would be to execute ‘axis tight’ for each plot/axis. This does what you’re looking for, just not “globally”

Comment: This helps much and saves so much time without causing much complication :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to set x and y axis limits to their min and max, use inf or -inf for the limits you want the axes to choose automatically. For example, axis([-inf 10 0 inf]) lets the axes choose the appropriate minimum x-axis limit and maximum y-axis limit.

Second, to set x and y axis limits globally, let ax_n = subplot(4,3,n) for each subplot. Then use axis([ax_1, ax_2, ax_3], [-inf inf -inf inf]) at the end to set all of the subplots simultaneously.

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,20); 
y = sin(x); 
figure(1) 
ax_1 = subplot(4,3,1)
plot(x,y)
title('Original')
fft_y = fft(y); 
ax_2 = subplot(4,3,2)
plot(abs(fft_y))
title('Spectrum')
ax_3 = subplot(4,3,3)
plot(angle(fft_y))
title('Phase')

axis([ax_1, ax_2, ax_3], [-inf inf -inf inf]);
```

Output:
[image]